# Gluten in beer or not?

Tags: diet, alcohol, nutrition, gluten

I've been trying to reduce my intake of gluten and have found that my bowels are much more stable and regular. Does beer have gluten in it? I haven't found beer to be a problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barley, the most common cereal used in beer, contains gluten. However, it is possible that the fermentation process digests this gluten, at least partially.

If you want to be on the safe side, you can try beer made out of rice or corn, as these are completely gluten free.